# How to optimize traversing a range of numbers?

Tags: c++

I am solving this problem:

> n prisoners, m sweets and s is the prisoner id. I start distributing m sweets from prisoner id s and keep on distributing one sweet to each of the n prisoners in a circular fashion. I need to find out which prisoner would get the last sweet.

Here is my solution:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t, n, m, s;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        cin>>n>>m>>s;
        int count = s;
        for(int i = 1; i < m; i++){
            count = (count + 1) % n;
        }
        cout << count << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

m, n and s lie between 1 and 10^9.
I am getting TLE (Time Limit Exceeded). How can I reduce time complexity for this problem?

Comment: What problem does that code actually try to solve? Also what do you mean with TLE? Are you doing silly online code judge problems?

Comment: n prisoners, m sweets and s is the prisoner id.
I start distributing m sweets from prisoner id s and keep on distributing one sweet to each of the n prisoners in a circular fashion. I need to find out which prisoner would get the last sweet.

Comment: Sweet. Also note, if you have working code and want to ask for ways improving it you should better ask at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AmanAgarwal Click [edit] and add this information to the question itself. It is also a good idea to explain TLE to visitors who never encountered online programming contests.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's the problem, the code isn't quite working - it times out (TLE stands for "Time Limit Exceeded").

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I well know that. It's simply poor wording in these kinds of questions coming up here, and are rarely well written.

Answer (score 0):

You should not optimize the traversal, you should eliminate it. Counting one-by-one is slow, so you need to come up with a mathematical formula to produce the count without a loop.

Fortunately, it is not too hard: you start from `s`, and you add one `m` times, mod `n`. Hence, you could compute `(s-1) % n` and `(m-1) % n`, add them together, take `% n` on the final result, and add `1` to convert zero-based result to one-based:

```
(((s-1) % n) + ((m-1) % n)) % n + 1
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/fGTfw0)

<sup>*</sup> Subtract one from `s` because `s` is one-based.
<sup>**</sup> Subtract one from `m` because the first item is distributed to the initial prisoner.